# What is a good example of the Flyweight Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, flyweight-pattern

String internment in c# is a good example.  Others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffer pools (especially when doing socket programming)

Answer (score 1):

This site has decent examples of all the deisgn patterns from GoF

http://dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx